# how to find the basis of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have to solve this exercise:

"Find the dimension and the base of $V$, where $V \subseteq R^{[x]^{<=3}}$ is the subspace of $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ such that $p'(2) = 0$"
$$
p'(2) = 12a+4b+c = 0
$$
my question is: how do i find a base of $p'(2)$?

Comment: $12a = - 4b -c$, take b and c as free variables you can have basis as two linear independent set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have that
$$V=\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d:12a+4b+c=0\}$$
Here we can arbitrarily choose, say, $a, b,d$ and take $c$ depending on them: $c=-12a-4b$.

To obtain a particular basis, just substitute $(1,0,0),\ (0,1,0),\ (0,0,1)$ in $(a,b,d)$.